# TikaException: Failed to close temporary resource - how to fix?

Tags: java, apache, maven, tesseract, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika on Windows 10, jre 1.8.0_181, and I've imported Tika using Maven with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
      <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have the code below for performing OCR using Tesseract (which I have independently tested and know to be working):

```
public static void OCRTest() {
        try {
            BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new File(OCR_IMAGE));
            TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
            config.setTessdataPath("C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata");
            config.setTesseractPath("C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR");
            ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
            parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
            TesseractOCRParser parser = new TesseractOCRParser();
            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            try {
                parser.parse(im, handler, metadata, parseContext);
                System.out.println(handler.toString());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TikaException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I run into the following exception:

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Failed to close temporary resources
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources.dispose(TemporaryResources.java:174)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser.parse(TesseractOCRParser.java:251)
    at test.test.App.OCRTest(App.java:46)
    at test.test.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\apache-tika-2643805894084124300.tmp: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

The tmp file is present in the Temp folder, and the exception seemed to come from not being able to delete it. On the Apache Tika forums, there is a [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1732) where someone else has run into the same exception, although with the AutoDetectParser and not Tesseract. Their issue seemed to be a conflict in their imported jars, but I run into this issue even with only the Apache Tika libraries installed.

I don't run into this issue when using the Tika's AutoDetectParser, only with the TesseractOCRParser. Any insights on how to fix the exception would be appreciated!

Comment: SysInternals have a tool for looking at what's holding a file open, maybe try that to see what process it is that's preventing the deletion of the temp file?

Comment: I took a look using Sysinternal's Process Explorer, and the only process holding it open was javaw.exe. This smells like a concurrency issue, but I can't seem to find where the conflict could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted on the Apache Tika issues forum (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2908). The issue came from the order the TesseractOCRParser was closing the open streams - you can see the changes made here: https://github.com/apache/tika/commit/8d386f827eb31e7f1cb189ce942c67a84a0c6bdc?diff=unified#diff-592f390e7558bb6a1fe1c5bc810fe4c8

For now, for anyone who runs into this issue, subclass TesseractOCRParser locally to include the above changes, which should be pushed in the next snapshot release.

Thanks to Tim @ Apache Tika!

Comment: Thank _you_ for opening the issue on our tracker!